# Operator== overloading of an abstract class and shared_ptr

Tags: c++, c++11, polymorphism, operator-overloading, shared-ptr

I want to use `std::find` on a list of a `shared_ptr` of an abstract class, but I'm getting an error. Is there even a way to compare two `shared_ptr` by dereferencing them in `std::find`?

Is it possible to maybe make a friend `operator==` that overloads `shared_ptr<A>`?

Minimal example:

```
#include "point.h"
#include <list>
#include <algorithm>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

class A {

protected:
    Point loc;
public:

    virtual void foo() = 0;

    virtual bool operator==(const Point& rhs) const = 0;
};

class B: public A {
    virtual void foo() override{}

    virtual bool operator==(const Point& rhs) const override {
        return rhs == loc;
    }
};

class C {

    list<shared_ptr<A>> l;
    void bar(Point & p) {

        const auto & f = find(l.begin(), l.end(), p); //<-- error is from here
    }
};
```

> Error  C2679   binary '==': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'const Point' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

Note: `Point` already has `operator==`.

Comment: But it is compared int terms of shared_ptr<A>::operator == ()

Comment: @DieterLücking I don't understand.

Comment: Try defining `bool operator==(const std::shared_ptr<A> &sp, const Point &point){return ((*sp) == point);}`

Comment: @Rames it says that it has too many parameters.

Comment: @kuhaku have you declared it outside class? It cannot be a class member.

Comment: Oh yeah it compiles now, why it can't be a member function? @Rames

Comment: @kuhaku because the lhs argument of member `operator==` is `this`, so it takes only one parameter more. Function I've written can be member of `std::shared_ptr<A>` and then it would look like `bool std::shared_ptr<A>::operator==(const Point &point){return ((**this) == point);}`. However the solution mentioned by Christophe is generally better in terms of clean and 'good code', if I were you, I would implement that one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Problem:

**[`find()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/find/)** is designed to find one precise **value** in an iterator range.

You have defined an `operator==` to compare an `A` with a `Point`.  But your list doesn't contain `A` objects but shared pointers to `A` objects. Unfortunately comparing a shared pointer to a Point is not something that is defined. This mismatch causes the error that you've reported.

### Solution:

An easy solution would be to use **[`find_if()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/find_if/)** instead of `find()`:  it doesn't look for a precise value, but for a predicate to become true:

```
   const auto & f = find_if(l.begin(), l.end(),[p](shared_ptr<A> &a){ return *a==p; });
```

Comment: It compiles. I knew lambda functions are cool, too bad our instructor dropped them, I'm gonna read up on them now.

Comment: Yes, lambdas are definitively cool.  Here a [quick intro](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/lambdas-in-c11/240168241) to start with.

Answer (score 1):

[`std::find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) can be implemented as

```
template<class InputIt, class T>
InputIt find(InputIt first, InputIt last, const T& value)
{
    for (; first != last; ++first) {
        if (*first == value) {
            return first;
        }
    }
    return last;
}
```

As you can see it is comparing `*first == value` which is translates to a `shared_ptr<A> == Point` when using `find(l.begin(), l.end(), p)`.  Since it is going to use `shared_ptr<A>::operator==` you are going to use `std::find_if` and write a custom compare function/functor that can compare those two types and pass it to `find`

You can learn more about functors at: [C++ Functors - and their uses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/356950/c-functors-and-their-uses)

Comment: Or to pass special function to `find`

Comment: I have no clue about functors, does the special function for `find` have to be a functor?

Comment: @kuhaku It doesn't have to be.  You can make a normal function and pass it to `find` as well.  Functors are suggested as they can be inlined which can make the code faster.

Comment: As far as I know, compare function cannot be argument of `find`. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/find/